# loading image into android imageView with ion returns a blurry result

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, blurry, android-ion

I'm trying to load an image from filesystem into an imageView with the ion library.

When I'm using the following code:

```
Ion.with(imageView)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.load(uri);
```

it (sometimes) results in a kind of blurry image.

When not using ion like the following the pictures appear sharply:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.toString()));
```

Is there a standard compression coming with ion that I can disable?

Strangely not every picture is blurry when using ion, e.g. I have two identical images, only with another name. When I load them into the imageView with ion one is blurry, one is not.

Any help or tips are appreciated!

Comment: Ion tries to load the image to fit the bounds of the imageview. So make sure your imageview is sized properly. Alternatively, if you use adjustViewBounds=true, it won't do that. or smartsize(false)

Comment: works great, that was what I was looking for! thank you very much for the explanation

Comment: Cool I added the answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ion tries to load the image to fit the bounds of the ImageView. So make sure your ImageView is sized properly in your layout. Alternatively, if you use adjustViewBounds=true to indicate the ImageView is adjusted by the image contents, it won't do that. Or alternatively smartsize(false).

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
Ion.with(context)
.load(url)
.withBitmap()
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.intoImageView(imageView);
```

Comment: this only seems to be the _long_ way of building an imageView request accoridng to the [documentation](https://github.com/koush/ion#load-an-image-into-an-imageview) and leads to the exact same result